# creating a simple exception for a class

Tags: php, oop, exception

I am creating a class called ex: foo

```
class foo{

 function __construct($arg){
    if(empty($arg)){
      throw new fooException('argument can not be empty');
    }
 }

}
```

I tried to create the class without passing anything through the constructor like this

```
try{
$o = new foo();
}catch(FooException $e){
 echo $e->getMessage(); 
}
```

I am getting error `Fatal error: Class 'FooException' not found in ..` 
I realize that, I need to extend maybe the error exception class, but there are no examples on how to do this in SO.

Comment: That's because there is no `FooException` class. Your class is just called `Foo`. See my answer below for an example of custom exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of defining a custom `Exception` called `FooException`.

The class that follows it, `TestException` tests this custom exception.

```
<?php
/**
 * Define a custom exception class
 */
class FooException extends Exception
{
    // Redefine the exception so message isn't optional
    public function __construct($message, $code = 0, Exception $previous = null) {
        // some code

        // make sure everything is assigned properly
        parent::__construct($message, $code, $previous);
    }

    // custom string representation of object
    public function __toString() {
        return __CLASS__ . ": [{$this->code}]: {$this->message}\n";
    }

    public function customFunction() {
        echo "A custom function for this type of exception\n";
    }
}

/**
 * Create a class to test the exception
 */
class TestException
{
    public $var;

    const THROW_NONE    = 0;
    const THROW_CUSTOM  = 1;
    const THROW_DEFAULT = 2;

    function __construct($avalue = self::THROW_NONE) {

        switch ($avalue) {
            case self::THROW_CUSTOM:
                // throw custom exception
                throw new FooException('1 is an invalid parameter', 5);
                break;

            case self::THROW_DEFAULT:
                // throw default one.
                throw new Exception('2 is not allowed as a parameter', 6);
                break;

            default: 
                // No exception, object will be created.
                $this->var = $avalue;
                break;
        }
    }
}


// Example 1
try {
    $o = new TestException(TestException::THROW_CUSTOM);
} catch (FooException $e) {      // Will be caught
    echo "Caught my exception\n", $e;
    $e->customFunction();
} catch (Exception $e) {        // Skipped
    echo "Caught Default Exception\n", $e;
}

// Continue execution
var_dump($o); // Null
echo "\n\n";


// Example 2
try {
    $o = new TestException(TestException::THROW_DEFAULT);
} catch (FooException $e) {      // Doesn't match this type
    echo "Caught my exception\n", $e;
    $e->customFunction();
} catch (Exception $e) {        // Will be caught
    echo "Caught Default Exception\n", $e;
}

// Continue execution
var_dump($o); // Null
echo "\n\n";


// Example 3
try {
    $o = new TestException(TestException::THROW_CUSTOM);
} catch (Exception $e) {        // Will be caught
    echo "Default Exception caught\n", $e;
}

// Continue execution
var_dump($o); // Null
echo "\n\n";


// Example 4
try {
    $o = new TestException();
} catch (Exception $e) {        // Skipped, no exception
    echo "Default Exception caught\n", $e;
}

// Continue execution
var_dump($o); // TestException
echo "\n\n";
?>
```

Source: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.extending.php
I modified it for your `FooException`

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 things here, first, the exception you are throwing is called "fooException", and then, the one you are catching, is called "FooException", this is not correct, maybe a typo?. Another thing is, did you create a class named "FooException" and load it in your application?

```
require_once(path/to/FooExceptionClass.php);
```

Hope this helps.